# Bootstrap - overwriting a font with a safe font like Arial

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

Title isn't accurate but I guess good enough.

Synopsis:  Company product uses bootstrap and our default font has been set to a specific free font; so all @site-font, @site-font-bold, etc are all pointing to specific woff files.

We have clients that we customize for.  One client wants Arial font for most everything.  I cannot seem to set @site-font-bold to Arial Bold - it displays Times New Roman.

How can I set all the @site-font-xxxx variables to various Arial fonts?

I used this for bold:
@site-font-bold: "Arial Bold";

Is it that Arial Bold should be something different?  I tried ArialBold - no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify `Arial Bold` as a font because the Bold variant comes under the Arial family and will be chosen by the browser when you have a `font-weight: bold` or similar property. I don't know what generator you are using but try setting `Arial` as the value for `@site-font-bold` and see if the bold text is displayed correctly.